USB bank + capacitor for flash gun
I have a camera flash (Godox TT350), which typically takes 2 AA cells. These cells do not last long, so I bought some dummy cells, which are connected to a USB plug.
The USB is inserted into a battery bank (to keep everything portable) and the USB plug steps the voltage down to 3v.
When the flash is turned on, it should show a red light after a few seconds to say it has charged enough to fire. It does not always charge up. I assume that the flash cannot pull enough power from the USB quick enough to charge, so it shows a 'low battery' warning and goes into standby.
Turning it on and off several times in quick succession seems to allow the flash to charge, presumably because it spikes a little when turned on...? So I thought, maybe a cap in between the bank and the flash might give the flash enough energy for its initial charge... It seems to work instantly sometimes, but then not at all other times.
Once it does get the initial charge, there is no problem for it recharging after each flash.
What logical thing am I overlooking to make the flash charge first time every time? I'm using a 1000uf cap, as that's all I have. The bank seems to go into standby if there is no load on the USB.
Thanks in advance

USB is inserted into a battery bank ... a USB what, is inserted?

how does a USB plug step down voltage? ... a USB plug is only a connector

the simplest is to try different USB power banks. you might also wire a resistor across the usb or battery contacts to keep the power bank alive. If the bank is on, and you have a capacitor charged across it, it should work the flash each time.

Most phone power banks cannot produce enough current for that flash. Though USB-C ports can pass amps of current, high current is only available from select power banks that have that output rating and that can recognize the specific handshake on the USB-C port that signals such current is allowed.
At a guess, the Godox flash can tolerate a Li-ion cell with a series diode or two.
A fresh AA Leclanché cell actually produces ~1.6 V, or 3.2 V for two in series, though that drops rapidly after a few minutes, loaded.
The common 18650 Li-ion cell produces ~4.2 V, open circuit, fully charged. With a silicon diode in series, that would drop to ~3.6 V O.C., only 10% or so higher than the original cells, likely within capabilities of the flash. One 18650 should last about as long as two AA's in series, and you could parallel those Li-ion cells (using a Si diode in series with each, to avoid equalization issues). The 18650 can produce high current and would likely suit your needs better.
Another option would be NiMH AA cells, a direct replacement for disposable AA's. NiMH chemistry under load produces only slightly less voltage than Leclanché.

Wow thanks for your responses. The USB plug must have some circuit inside it that reduces the voltage. It is a larger than normal plug - almost like a memory stick at the end of the wires connected to the dummy cells.
